# Bitbake vs. cmake for x86 and arm project

Tags: cmake, bitbake

I have a layered cmake project with a hierarchy of libraries and applications. Each of these libraries and applications has a CMakeLists.txt and a top level CMakeLists.txt that includes the sub-cmake files.

Right now we are developing and testing entirely on an x86 Linux platform but at some point we will want to start pulling the code into a Yocto build and target arm. We want to maintain being able to build for both x86 and arm.

I've seen some Yocto guides on building for x86 but these appear to build the entire world (the toolchain, linux kernel, all libraries etc) and run the image via qemu. For our desktop use this is quite a bit of overkill when our machines have compilers and we can just run the applications directly, but it would be very helpful to have bitbake build some libraries that we have dependencies on and that need to be installed to a 'virtual root'.

How can I use use bitbake for native x86 projects (in place of or in addition to cmake) and be able to leverage the recipe files for Yocto later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with Yocto, but I'm using another embedded Linux distribution with similar concept: [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). Buildroot creates toolchainfile (output/host/usr/share/buildroot/toolchainfile.cmake) for the currently selected toolchain.

You create two output folders for your project:

```
build-x86
build-arm
```

I the first folder you just execute:

```
cmake ../path-to-your-source
```

In the second one:

```
cmake ../path-to-your-source -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../path-to-buildroot/output/host/usr/share/buildroot/toolchainfile.cmake
```

If Yocto provides a toolchainfile, you can use it directly. If not you can create it yourself. See this [wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#The_toolchain_file).

**Update:**

This [section](http://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_infrastructure_for_cmake_based_packages) explains, how you can add your software to Buildroot (package). [Here](http://free-electrons.com/blog/buildroot-2011-11/) the *source folder override mechanism* is described.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really addressing the issue I'm having. I don't need a toolchain, or kernel etc built with the x86 environment, but I do need some kind of dependency system to ensure X is built before Y. If I had the same system that could do both that and the embedded toolchain, kernel etc that would be the ideal.

Comment: FYI: have you looked at [ScratchBox2](http://alexandernst.blogspot.de/2013/03/cross-compiling-applications-for-arm.html)?

Comment: In my approach you should build entire Buildroot only once, to generate arm toolchain and library dependencies. After that you can compile your software the same way, you do it for x86. But it won't help to install dependencies on the 'virtual root'.

Comment: But what if I'm building for x86 and don't require an arm toolchain? The goal is to use a similar system to build both x86 and arm binaries, but be able to skip the toolchain portions when building for x86 as those are things we can install via a package manager like yum.

Comment: For x86 you create **build-x86** folder either in your project folder or elsewhere (it is called out-of-source build). Then you just go to this folder and execute `cmake ../path-to-your-source` as you would usually do for CMake. When you call **make** afterwards your software will be compiled with **gcc**, that you already installed via **yum**. In your **build-arm** folder you invoke cmake with the path to the toolchain file, so when you call make, your software will be crosscompiled for arm. This way you have one folder with source code and two independent build folders.

Comment: Yep, we do this today with cmake for x86. When we switch to the emdedded approach we will want to switch to using Yocto/bitbake as it will take care of a lot more of the embedded dependency generation, such as kernels, toolchains etc. I was hoping to use bitbake for both the x86 and arm builds.

Comment: Btw. bitbake and CMake are different things. CMake is "equivalent" for autotools and bitbake is for packaging. I mean, it describes, how to package software that is based on autotools, cmake or simple Makefile. It manages package dependencies etc. So you can leave your software by using CMake and use bitbake to package it together with dependencies. You don't need to choose between them.

Comment: Ahh ok. This makes sense. I'm still a bit lost as to how I might use bitbake on the desktop. Should I just look at some recipes and build out from nothing? I haven't found any reference to using bitbake to build out dependencies from scratch or using bitbake to coordinate a desktop build process.